# Angular.copy changing reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

When I am trying to copy a new object to an old object via `angular.copy`, its reference gets changed. If I use `=` or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newObj))`, the view is not updated with new value.

How can I solve this?

Code example:

```
$scope.value = newValue.ref;
```

View is not updated in this instance.

```
$scope.value = angular.copy(newValue.ref);
```

View is updated, but reference is changed.

Comment: Show your html file also.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the reference, use the two argument form of angular.copy:

```
//$scope.value = angular.copy(newValue.ref);

//USE two argument signature
angular.copy(newValue.ref, $scope.value);
```

This way the original reference is preserved.

> ### Usage
>
> `angular.copy(source, [destination]);`
>
> Creates a deep copy of `source`, which should be an object or an array.
>
> - if a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.
>
> [— AngularJS angular.copy API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)